# keypress event on mac os: pressing key longtime for special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a very robust, crossbrowser solution that will work in different os to get the key that is pressed in an input field.

i am using this code:

```
$('form').on('keypress', function(e) {
var code = e.charCode || e.keyCode;

/// if no whitespace:
if (String.fromCharCode(code).replace(/\s/g, "").length > 0) {
    eingabe = String.fromCharCode(code);
    console.log("eingabe: " + eingabe); 
}
});
```

but i have problems on mac os when i press a key on the keyboard for longer time i can select a special character by typing a number. For example for "e" 1: é 2:è 3:ê 4:ë 5:ė.

Like this:

[image]

This will not work with keypress, that is clear but what can i do to fix this to get the right value? I really need a robust solution for this that will work on different os, browsers etc to get the character that is typed in the input. In this case not the "e" but the "é" and so on.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried e.which? https://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Comment: yes, but the result is the same: "e" gets keydown "51", but "é" gets keydown "51" and "49" for the "1". Is there a good library that will help me handle this?